# binding winforms to database by entity framework 6

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

The scenario is simple:

1. I have EF6 DbContext MyDbContext
2. I have Form with ListBox
3. The code to bind data from DB to listbox is as follows:

   ```
   dbContext = new MyDBContext();
   listBox1.DataSource = dbContext.Experiments.Select(a => a.Name + "," + a.ModificationDate.Second).ToList();
   ```
4. I have button to Add a row to DB table with code:

   ```
    dbContext.Experiments.Add(new Models.Experiment()
       {
           CreationDate = DateTime.Now,
           ModificationDate = DateTime.Now,
           Description = "Test" + DateTime.Now.Second,
           Name = "test" + DateTime.Now.Second
       });
       dbContext.SaveChanges();
   ```

Now I would like to automatically refresh positions in my listbox. What is the best approach to do that? I know that I can rewrite code from point 3 but I would like to have it all two way binding and automatically updated

Comment: The code from point 3 sets DataSource to be a plain list, if you want binding to work two ways, you need to set DataSource to be a collection that supports that e.g. BindingList, so it could raise events that would update the control

Answer (score 1):

I think that "data binding" is a keyword here. Generally in WinForms two way bidning is provided by classes like  [BindingList<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx) or [BindingSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The question is how to use them together with EF. I think that an extension method [ToBindingList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn237205%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) can be useful here. However, I don't have a lot of experience with using it. I suggest you to look at the following article: [Entity Framework Databinding with WinForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj682076.aspx). Besides, if you search for *ToBindingList EntityFramework* on stackoverflow you will find many related questions.

**UPDATE**

I made a small test and I see a potential problem. The automatic synchronization between a control and EF will work if you use the same data context (the same instance of DbContext class). It means that a context may have a long life-cycle what is not recommended.